# getting a color from a database entry and applying it to a label background

Tags: database, vb.net, colors, runtime, user-input

I am having trouble getting the color the user picks and saving it into a database so that when they reload the program it will automatically apply to the  labels background.

I have this to let the user chose the color

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    If ColorDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Quiz.LTitle.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

Then i have a button to save it with the code so far as

```
Private Sub BTitleSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTitleSave.Click
    BackGroundWork.Title_SettingsBindingSource.AddNew()
    BackGroundWork.Title_BColorTextBox.Text = Quiz.LTitle.BackColor.ToArgb

    BackGroundWork.Title_SettingsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    BackGroundWork.Title_SettingsTableAdapter.Update(BackGroundWork.QuizSettingsDataSet)
End Sub
```

BackGroundWork is a form where i have all my databases running
Quiz is the form that everyone will see.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try ColorInHex ...

```
Private Sub BTitleSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTitleSave.Click
    BackGroundWork.Title_SettingsBindingSource.AddNew()
    BackGroundWork.Title_BColorTextBox.Text = Quiz.LTitle.BackColor.ToArgb.ToString("X")

    BackGroundWork.Title_SettingsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    BackGroundWork.Title_SettingsTableAdapter.Update(BackGroundWork.QuizSettingsDataSet)
End Sub
```

When you called it ..

```
Dim sColor as String = ... -> this retrieve from database

Quiz.LTitle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(sColor)
```

Hope this works for you !